# Identification of Anoles

Tags: species-identification, reptile, herpetology

Can anyone help me identify these anole species? All photos taken on St. Thomas, USVI, in close proximity to one another.

<sup>(click to zoom in)</sup>

[image: Specimen 1]
[image: Specimen 2]
[image: Specimen 3]
[image: Specimen 4]
[image: Specimen 5]

Each photo is a different individual, but the overall similarity makes me think they are likely the same species, although I could easily be wrong about that (the third one especially looks different from the others). They are dull brown overall with fairly subtle patterning, a light line that runs down their spine, bordered by a darker stripe on either side, and a broad band between the eyes. My best guess is that they are either Brown Anoles (*A. sagrei*) or Crested Anoles (*A. cristatellus*). Searching images online, there are some images identified for each species that are quite similar to these, but based just on comparison with those images, I really could go either way. Is there a definitive criteria to help narrow down the species?

Comment: Note: Usually I'd say that a single question asking for multiple identifications is too broad, but because I think these may be the same species, I felt it was appropriate to group them into one.

Comment: If they're not the same species. Whoever answers first, please make it a community wiki.

Comment: @canadianer. Looks organised. But they can't be zoomed in, looks like it would require some other markdown.